# Is there a way to reduce laptop's resolution from 4K to HD, without text distortion, so that it runs faster and uses less battery?

Tags: windows-10, lenovo-laptop

Is there a way to reduce laptop's resolution from 4K to HD, without text distortion, so that it runs faster and uses less battery?

My laptop is Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro.

Comment: Reducing the resolution of your display isn't going to result in your laptop running faster or extend the device's battery life

Comment: Battery life will have very little effect. Lowering brightness will improve battery life though. About resolution, I have noticed that games (full screen) perform better in low resolution (more FPS) and remote desktop also give good performance if I use low resolution will less colors (16 bit instead of 32 bit). In other daily activities, I did not see any improvement in performance.